# How to get shipped orders data from Shipstation using Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping

I am trying to get shipped orders data from [ShipStation](https://www.shipstation.com/) to Google sheets, when I looked into [Developer tools](https://www.shipstation.com/docs/api/orders/list-orders/), I found the following javascript code to get the orders list:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Host", "ssapi.shipstation.com");
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "__YOUR_AUTH_HERE__");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://ssapi.shipstation.com/shipments", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

The orders I am trying to fetch can be found on the following link in my account:

> https://ship13.shipstation.com/orders/shipped

I tried to use it in Google apps script but apps script does not recognize `new Headers()` method and and I have been able to do the following conversion due to my novice skills:

```
    function Test(){
    
       const apiKey = "###"; // Please set your API key.
       const url = 'https://ssapi.shipstation.com/shipments';

       var options = {
      'method': 'GET',
      "contentType": 'application/json',
      "followRedirects" : false,
      'headers': {
        'Host': 'ssapi.shipstation.com',
        'Authorization': 'apiKey'
  }
};

     var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
     Logger.log(response);
       }
```

But it gives following error message everytime I try to run it:

> Exception: Attribute provided with invalid value: Header:Host

I have obtained `API and Secret Key` from my ShipStation account also. I found this [source](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/shipstation-odbc-mysql-apps-script.rst) to get ShipStation data into Google sheet however it only works with MySQL Remoting Service which is not really helpful in this case. Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw the sample curl command from your provided URL, it seems that `Host` is not included in the request header. And also, UrlFetchApp cannot set `Host` in the request header. I think that this might be the reason for your current issue of `Exception: Attribute provided with invalid value: Header:Host`. So, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function Test() {
  const apiKey = "###"; // Please set your API key.
  const url = 'https://ssapi.shipstation.com/shipments';
  var options = { 'headers': { 'Authorization': apiKey } };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

- It seems that [the sample curl command in the official document](https://www.shipstation.com/docs/api/shipments/list/#example-request) is as follows. So, when the above script occurs an error, please confirm the query parameters and your API key, again.

  ```bash
  curl -iX GET 'https://ssapi.shipstation.com/shipments?recipientName=recipientName&recipientCountryCode=recipientCountryCode&orderNumber=orderNumber&orderId=orderId&carrierCode=carrierCode&serviceCode=serviceCode&trackingNumber=trackingNumber&createDateStart=createDateStart&createDateEnd=createDateEnd&shipDateStart=shipDateStart&shipDateEnd=shipDateEnd&voidDateStart=voidDateStart&voidDateEnd=voidDateEnd&storeId=storeId&includeShipmentItems=includeShipmentItems&sortBy=sortBy&sortDir=sortDir&page=page&pageSize=pageSize' \
  -H 'Authorization: __YOUR_AUTH_HERE__' \
  ```

#### Note:

- If your `###` of `const apiKey = "###"` doesn't include the API secret, how about the following modification?

  ```js
  function Test() {
    const apiKey = "###"; // Please set your API key.
    const apiSecret = "###"; // Please set your API secret.
    const url = 'https://ssapi.shipstation.com/shipments';
    var options = { 'headers': { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(`${apiKey}:${apiSecret}`) } };
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    Logger.log(response);
  }
  ```

  - When the above script occurs the same error 401, please modify `${apiKey}:${apiSecret}` to `${apiSecret}:${apiKey}`.

Comment: Thank you, this is example data that I am trying to get: https://www.shipstation.com/docs/api/shipments/list/, when I ran your script, received the following error: `Exception: Request failed for https://ssapi.shipstation.com returned code 401.`

Comment: @Roomi Thank you for replying. `code 401` is due to `the client request has not been completed because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the`. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) In this case, please check your `apiKey` again.

Comment: @Roomi By the way, in the official document, it seems that API key and API Secret are required to be used. Although, unfortunately, I cannot know your `###` of `const apiKey = "###";`, in your actual script, you are using those values. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Roomi Thank you for replying. I added one more sample script for using the API key and API secret. Could you please confirm it? And, I would like to remove your latest comment including your API key and API secret if those are the valid values.